# Can i delete images left in media/import/ folder

Tags: magento-1, product-images, import, delete

Once i have imported my product images from the media/import folder in magento - is it safe to delete them from that folder?

I want to delete them to save disk space but want to make sure deleting them won't suddenly mean missing product images throughout my catalogue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes after you have imported all the images and it works fine, you can delete all that images in that folder to free up disk space

Answer (score 0):

If disk space is an issue and it often is when you are paying for backups, when using the Magento import tool be aware that running it multiple times can lead to multiple copies of images being copied into the media folder (they have a 2 in their name).  That can really ramp up your disk usage. So best thing to do is to confirm your import is working, delete all the contents of the media/catalog/product folder and run the import freshly.